# Font line spacing in Firefox on Windows 7 vs Windows XP

Tags: html, css, windows, firefox, font-size

I am using Verdana font for text paragraph. The problem is that in Firefox v16 on Windows XP this text renders different than Firefox v16 on Windows 7. Internet Explorer 9 renders font without any issues on Windows 7. The difference is in line spacing - in Firefox / XP and IE / 7 line spacing is a bit narrower than Firefox / 7. I am using default settings for both Firefox and Internet Explorer on Windows 7.

So what I am talking about is not horizontal character spacing it is vertical line spacing.

As far as I know, Verdana is a standard font for XP and Win7 so there should be no issues with that.

Any CSS code to fix this and make the spacing identical in IE and Firefox on Windows 7?

Comment: Share the url to the page in question. Or post the code (html+css).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't have an XP machine nearby but did you setup a custom `line-height` in your CSS? You said "I am using default settings" so that makes me think you didn't set a fixed `line-height`. If i misunderstood i apologize.

Comment: The defaults might conceivably be different, though I cannot see a difference. (This might depend on the content of the text, font size, etc.) In any case, the default line height for Verdana is far too small for most purposes, something like 1.125. Due to the characteristics of Verdana, a value like 1.3 might be more suitable (depends on line length, among other things).

Comment: Line-height was a problem. Thanks.